# When did Bobby Fischer move from New York to California?

Tags: history, fischer

As title above, when did Bobby Fischer move from Brooklyn, New York, to California, where did he actually locate, and why did he leave New York?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobby_Fischer#Brady2011): "Brady 2011, p. 9. "The family lived in [California, Idaho, Oregon, Illinois, and Arizona] before moving to New York.""

Comment: I was asking for details about when did Bobby leave New York - in the late 1960s - (or early 1970s?), not about when his family moved to New York in the early 1940s.

Answer (score 1):

It’s just a guess, but it could be because he started following Herbert Armstrong who was in California. Fischer did donate *lots* of money to him and was reported riding in his jet plane with him. As I recall, it would have been in the 70s or possibly the 80s.

Comment: Although there are no sources, I strongly feel, too, that Fischer moved to California because of his involvment with the Worldwide Church of God. Perhaps Frank  Brady’s “Endgame”, his ultimate Fischer biography, has some details?